# Conditional closing on ContextMenuStrip

Tags: vb.net

I have ContextMenuStrip with such items:

```
OpenToolStripMenuItem
WrapToolStripMenuItem
CopyToolStripMenuItem
PasteToolStripMenuItem
```

where WrapToolStripMenuItem have checkbox. Other items don't have.
So, code for that item look's as follows:

```
Private Sub WrapToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles WrapToolStripMenuItem.Click

    WrapToolStripMenuItem.Checked = Not WrapToolStripMenuItem.Checked
End Sub
```

I find some workable solution for ContextMenu which leave menu opened when they try to close:

```
Private Sub ContextMenuStrip1_Closing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownClosingEventArgs) Handles ContextMenuStrip1.Closing

    If (e.CloseReason = ToolStripDropDownCloseReason.ItemClicked) Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

All of that work OK.

Questin is:
How to suppress closing a menu ONLY when ClickedItem is WrapToolStripMenuItem and not other?
How to recognize which item was clicked in _Closing handler without using local variables like "lastpressedmenuitem" or similar?

Comment: Yes, you need a variable.  It is ugly, you'll have to set it in every Click event handler.  Making context menus behave like they do in every other program that the user is familiar with is never the wrong thing to do.  He *expects* the menu to close when he clicks.

Comment: As I can see local variable have to go not in _Click handler but in every _MouseDown handler. Well, if we have possibility to manage _Closing handler in order to Cancel closing then it can't be true that menu is expected to be closed after click. You see many foreign applications with checkboxes, radio and toggle buttons (or groups) which dont closes on click.

Comment: It can't be a local variable, it has to be a field of your Form class.  So it retains its value between events.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your explanation. I get it working successfully.